# How to reference the entire dataLayer object in a custom HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am pushing redux dispatch events to the dataLayer. I am appending some information to the object and they end up being fairly complex objects. I have a custom html tag that fires when certain properties on the dataLayer object are certain values. The custom tag calls a window.publish() function that publishes a JSON object to an ELK stack. The window.publish() function takes and object as the argument: window.publish({"key":"value"}) .

What I want to do is publish the entire dataLayer object for the tag that is being fired. I know I can reference single variables on the object using {{}} notation, but how can I reference the entire object? Currently I'm doing this:

```
<script>
window.publish(
  dataLayer[
   dataLayer.findIndex(function(ev){return ev['gtm.uniqueEventId'] == . 
     {{UniqueEventId}}})
  ]);
 </script>
```

where {{UniqueEventId}} is a custom variable I've setup.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `dataLayer.find(yourfunc)`

Comment: I've gotten this answer on the Google Product Forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tag-manager/cskdJPfJF1k/7L52mbwkAQAJ
I'll update it here if no other ideas come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm using in the question is the answer. It comes from here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tag-manager/cskdJPfJF1k/7L52mbwkAQAJ